# version of BotFramework targetting .NET 6?

Tags: botframework

Sorry to post here such a generic question, but is there any work in progress to release a new version of Bot Framework for .NET 6 ?

Regards

JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is in progress already.

Please see here:
https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/5977